# How to register a ServiceWorker back

Tags: javascript, html, css, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm testing with service workers and today i unregistered my sw from devtools and now everytime when I reload my website I see in the application window the service worker of my webiste being "deleted" and I can't click anything.My question is how can I bring it back?I tried everything...

Answer (score 0):

Try clean cache of application and then rebuild your application. In code of application you should register service worker.